# Confused over which is more grammatically correct here: ～たことをごめんなさい or ～たことはごめんなさい

Tags: grammar, particles

> この世に生まれたこと**を**本当にごめんなさい！
>   この世に生まれたこと**は**本当にごめんなさい！

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid but both are unnatural.
生まれてきてごめんなさい is more natural.
〜て＋ごめんなさい is natural usage.